# Deployment to test, acceptance en production with certificate on production

Tags: azure, deployment

We deploy a Worker Role to Azure. We have 3 different environments (test, acceptance, production). There's a certificate only on production, so when we deploy we only want to use the certificate configuration on that environment. We can create different Service Configurations based on the Service Definition but we can't specify a configuration to use or not use a certificate, it's either all configurations or none. What is the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little complex in terms of the msbuild xml that you need, but it is possible to create an xdt transform for your csdef files allowing you to have a different configuration for each environment.
See [this post](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/apply-xdt-transforms-to-your-servicedefinition-csdef-file/) for the code you need. I just found [another post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2012/07/02/transform-windows-azure-service-model-files-during-packaging.aspx) that looks really handy too.

Comment: Thanks will look into that, let you know if this works